# Cannot make static reference to nonstatic method issue

Tags: android

I am writing my first viewpager program in android by following the example at: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/

The example uses two fragments: detailsfragment which contains a textview and a image fragment which contains a imageview. Here is the code for the image fragment:

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
private final int imageResourceId ;

public ImageFragment (int imageResourceId)
{
    this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
}
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("Test","Hello");
}
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   

    savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, container,false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    **ImageView.setImageResource(imageResourceId);**

    return view;
}

}
```

I am having cannot make static reference to nonstatic function setImageResource(int) from the type imageview(Problem statement in bold). How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
ImageView.setImageResource(imageResourceId);
```

with

```
imageView.setImageResource(imageResourceId);
```

Actually, you're trying to call the method `setImageResource` directly from the `ImageView` class, but since this method isn't static you couldn't call it from there. I think you just mistyped the variable name.

Comment: Stupid error, I must admit, thank you :)

Comment: A related question is, how to set up an event handler for a view inside a fragment, such as the imageview above?

Comment: You could add the attribute `android:onClick` in your xml file for the ImageView element.